# Print a text file (*.txt) using PrintService API java

Tags: java, printing

In my Java application, I create a text file and save it into a specific directory.
I want the user can print this file so I'm following this procedure:

```
if (reportFile.exists())
{
  PrintService [] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
  PrintService chosenPrinter = JOPtionPane.... //choice it with a JOptionPane
  DocFlavor [] flavors = chosenPrinter.getSupportedDocFlavors();
  DocFlavor printFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(reportFile);
  Doc document = new SimpleDoc (fis, printFormat, null);
  PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
  aset.add(new Copies(1)); 
  aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED); 
  DocPrintJob job = chosenPrinter.createPrintJob(); 
  try 
    { 
      job.print(document, aset); 
    } 
    catch (PrintException pe) 
    {
      System.out.println("====PrintException======="+pe);
    }                   
}
```

With `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM_AUTOSENSE`, I've no exception but what I get is a blank page (I'm using a PDF creator printer for the moment), and if I try to set a different DocFlavor, I'll get an invalid flavor exception.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: hi,were you able to fix this issue?